# What is the best way to do my shopify app to a Partner Friendly app

Tags: shopify

My app is in the Shopify App Store. I have analyzed that the Dev Stores are installing my app but not using it on live stores. as my app is a paid app. I want my app to be a partner-friendly app. Please provide any suggestions.

Comment: which app you have listed? what it's functionality. Good documentation and support will always help your app to get in rank.

Comment: My app link is [here](https://apps.shopify.com/crm-connector-1) @BhargavKaklotara